# Resizing UIButton Frame While Using Size Classes Requires Auto Layout

Tags: uibutton, resize, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have used storyboard to layout a custom cell in a tableview. I have a UI button in this custom cell that has an initial x,y size of 60x7. This UI button (as with all objects in the storyboard) use auto layout with size classes.

When the user clicks on an edit button in the view, I would like to change the size of the UIButton in each cell to be 60x60. Various StackOverflow solutions for changing the UIButton size do something like the following:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = cell.button1Left.frame;
buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
cell.button1Left.frame = buttonFrame;
```

But the solutions also warn that this will not work unless you turn off auto layout. However, when I try to turn off auto layout for this UIButton in the custom cell, I get the following warning:

[image]

This warning scares me. If I disable size classes, will this mess up my layout, disable my segues, and make future changes more difficult? If so, is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying?

Bonus question: is it possible to animate the resizing of the UIButton (i.e. so that it appears to stretch to the larger size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the best solution for me was to create another UIButton that was already the desired size. When the user presses an edit button for the view, I hide the collapsed UIButton that was 60x7. Then I unhide the full size UIButton that is 60x60. To animate the transition so that it looks more natural, I did the following:

```
        [UIView transitionWithView:cell.pencilButtonLeft
                          duration:0.6
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                        animations:NULL
                        completion:NULL];
        cell.pencilButtonLeft.hidden = NO;
```

As for the warning message when I tried to turn off autosizing, I decided to not turn off autoresizing and not to disable size classes. In reading it closely, I might have been ok as long as I did not have an intention of running the app on a device other than an iPhone. Thanks to @Ptah for the suggestion on the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) add 2 constraints to your Button in storyboard;

2) create properties for them :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *btnHeight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *btnWidth;
```

3) add action to button click:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    self.btnHeight.constant +=50;
    self.btnWidth.constant +=50;

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.7 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

P.S. If your button is in the center of cell, you need also create top and left constraints and if you make height and width for 50 bigger you need to make top and left for 25 smaller.

Comment: I get the gist of what you are suggesting, but its not quite aligning with my situation. When I say that a user presses an edit button, its not the same button as the one that needs to be resized. So I don't have an Action that identifies the button as the sender. Also, wouldn't your suggestion require the IBOutlet to be connected on the storyboard? I tried to make the connection, but it doesn't recognize a connectable object for the cell. Seems that I would need to make these IBOutlets be part of a subclassed UIButton that I am trying to resize. Thoughts?

Comment: @JeffB6688 are you sure you add constraints to the button before to search connectable objects?  You could save links to all your buttons in some `NSMuttableArray *myBtns`. And when edit button will be pressed  `[myBtns makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(..)];`

Comment: Yes, I already had constraints for both width and height for the UIButton. So I did not add new ones. While I did not use your answer, it gave me food for thought (specifically with respect to the animation). So thank you for that.